# Does drush stop events from firing and/or bypass event subscribers?

Tags: drush, event-subscribers

I'm running some migrations and have logic dependent on their Events

```
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[MigrateEvents::POST_IMPORT][] = ['onMigratePostImport'];
    return $events;
  }
```

When I run a migration from the UI my `onMigratePostImport()` runs as expected. However, I just tried running the same migrations via drush and that logic appears not to have run. Would using drush cause these events to be bypassed/not fired?

Comment: I don't think so, as I'm using events to populate redirect creation during migration, all ran from drush.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Wonder what's stopping things up on my end. Glad to hear that theoretically it should be working.

Comment: Make sure you use the latest drush version.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a logic that exclude the CLI on your event  or an event that runs before yours? something like:

if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli'){
   return,
}